# Reportlab Table Index Error

Tags: python-3.x, reportlab

I'm very confused as I've done this before but it has stopped working.  I get an index error that implies I have 4 columns and 1 row but 4 rows of data.

```
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter
from reportlab.platypus import Table, SimpleDocTemplate
story = []

fielddata = ('DATE ',  '1', '2', '3')
colwidths = (40,  20,  20,  20)
rowheights = (20)
t = Table(fielddata, colwidths,  rowheights)
story.append(t)
doc = SimpleDocTemplate('scoreboard.pdf',pagesize = letter, topMargin=0)
doc.build(story)
```

Comment: On what line is the error occurring?

Comment: Have you tried making `rowheights` a tuple, e.g. `rowheights = (20,)` Note that the comma makes it a tuple NOT the parens/brackets.